# Proper game structure

Tags: java, structure

To preface, sorry for the semi-vague question. I have been searching for weeks to this question.
So I understand the necessities a game needs. (init, update, draw).

To be more specific, I'm using Java with Slick2D as a learning environment. Slick2D makes the set-up of the game pretty simple. I think I understand MVC structure, but my biggest problem right now is where do I write the player movement code?

I have the Player class which has all the fields of where it's at, what image/animation it needs to render, and right now, all of the controls. It doesn't feel right, though that could just be my own insecurities. I feel that the player movement controls should be in its own class, the collision detection in its own class, and the all the player would have is simply what defines it(coordinates, size, hit box, etc.).

I'm not entirely sure how to explain this, as every time I think about it, my mind races all over the place and I have a hard time "chunking" this information in my head.
If you need more information, please let me know. I'm just trying to find the "right" place for everything to make my code more manageable, readable, and possibly reusable.

(edited to show program flow[not runnable]) As it is, my flow is,

```
public class Game extends StateBasedGame{
  //with main included, this sets up the window, fps, etc...
  start "level 1" state...;
}

public class level1 extends BasicGameState{

  public void init(){
  initialize player, environment, etc...
  }

  public void update(){
    player.update();
  }

  public void render(){
    environment.render();
    player.render();
  }

}

public class Player{
  All player variables

  public Player(){
    construct player with coords and starting image/animation
  }

  public void init(){
    initializes all images/animations this player could potentially use
  }

  public void update(){
    All environment based input controls go here, example;
      if(this.isGrounded && input.keyIsDown(KEY_SPACE){
        make character jump;
        change animation;
      }
   }

   public void render(){
     draw image/animation;
   }

  }
```

Comment: Why not look at other people's code to see how they do things? That may give you some good ideas. Also, to make your question more concrete, could you edit it to include a small diagram or indented list with your current architecture? We may be able to criticize or improve it...

Comment: I added some pseudo-code to show how my program "flows" maybe this could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collision detection should be taken care of in the update method. If you mean movement from input, you should create a separate class for input. Store the position coordinates for a character in the character object. The Input class should then change these coordinates. If you are talking about an AI you should have a separate AI class that controls the movement.

Every game is different. The important part is that you understand the code and that it works. I recommend finding helpful online tutorials that show example code so you can begin to understand the workflow of creating a game.

Comment: Thank you. I think I did mean movement from input. So along with what you said, I should also have another class that should handle what image/animation the player is currently using, outside of the player class, right?

I know it's important for me to understand the code, but I'm thinking long term and potentially working with other people. I don't want to sit and explain what every class does. (I know a lot of that is param/class/method naming and comments) 
So for movement from input, I should have that input class inside of my main game's update method?
Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: @surlistyc: the Player class, which is strictly a *logical* class, and the View classes, including images and animations, should most definitely be separate since their responsibilities are quite distinct.